# Cannot deploy the IPA file to the iPhone

Tags: ios, xamarin, deployment, ipa

What can be a reason that I cannot install the IPA file on one device and can on another?
The device that works Ok is the iPad version 9.3.5, and the "problem" device is the iPhone version 11.1.2.

The IPA file is created with Xamarin in VS 2015.

Where to look into?
Thanks.

Comment: How is the IPA signed?  TestFlight, AdHoc or Development?  If AdHoc or Development, is the iPhone registered in the app's provisioning profile?

Comment: Have you added the `iPhone's UDID` to the  app's provisioning profile for testing?